# use of equals() method in comparator interface?

Tags: java

`equals()` method is available to all java collection classes from the `Object` class. This method is also declared in `Comparator` interface, so what is the purpose of declaring this method in Comparator? in which case is it used and how?

Answer (score 10):

> what is the purpose of declaring this method in Comparator?

I think it's the designer's way of highlighting the fact that `Comparator.equals()` imposes some [additional requirements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) on any classes that implement the interface:

> Additionally, this method can return `true` only if the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator. Thus, `comp1.equals(comp2)` implies that `sgn(comp1.compare(o1, o2))==sgn(comp2.compare(o1, o2))` for every object reference `o1` and `o2`.

The method can be used to establish whether or not two distinct comparators impose the same order.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the main reason is to make it clear that `equals` method is for testing the *`Comparator` itself*.  This is obvious when you think about it, but can I imagine that some people might expect `equals(Object)` to (somehow) be semantically related to the `compare(T, T)` method.

It also allows the documentation of some common-sense guidelines for when two comparators could be viewed as equal.

Either way, the presence of the `equals(Object)` method in the interface is *solely* for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 4):

From the javadoc

> Note that it is ***always*** safe ***not*** to override Object.equals(Object).
>   However, overriding this method may, in some cases, improve
>   performance by allowing programs to determine that two distinct
>   comparators impose the same order.

The idea is simply to be able to allow you to not sort a collection that has already been sorted by another comparator if you realize that the end result will be the same.

Generally it had little use, but when sorting very large collections it is something you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

-when the declaring Comparator is compared to another Object (argument)

Answer (score 0):

It's just an over-ridden form of the Object's equals method to let you know if two objects are of same comparator type.

Answer (score -2):

As per your question I think It is used to compare objects after converting in string.
Object class eqlas methods chek both Object are eqls or not And Competres method chek object data like Hello.eqlas("hello")