# Why is it not necessary to override both methods of interface Comparator in Java

Tags: java, interface, comparator

We know that it is necessary to implement all methods of an interface, if we want to make an object of that class. But why is it not necessary to implement both the methods `compare()` and `equals()` of interface `Comparator` in java?

I agree that the purpose is solved but even then why is it not mandatory to override `equals`() if we override `compare`()?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ While a good read, that is mainly for `Comparable#compareTo(T)`, not `Comparator#compare(Object,Object)` and only briefly says "Be aware that if a Comparator compares only one of several significant fields, then the Comparator is very likely not synchronized with equals."

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of equals() method in comparator interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498148/use-of-equals-method-in-comparator-interface)

Comment: If you read the linked Question / Answers, you should understand what `equals` *means* for a Comparator ... and hence why overriding it is wrong / pointless.

Answer (score 7):

Since all classes implicitly extend `Object` every implementation of a `Comparator` has an equals method, because every `Object` has one.

It would be the same if you define an interface with a toString() method.

```
 public interface ToString {
      public String toString();
 }

 public class SomeClass implements ToString {
     // toString implicitly implemented, because Object defines it
 }
```

When you look at the class it says "implements ToString" and this is true, isn't it?

Comment: thanks for ur answer. is comparator() method also overridden by Object or just only equals() method.

Comment: @user162114 No -- look at the methods that are part of Object. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: Only equals. take a look at the java api doc of object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Comment: @RenéLink: `toString`, not `ToString`.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is already overridden by `java.lang.Object` on every object you can create.

Answer (score 2):

*Every* object implicitly has an [equals from Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (as every object is a sub-type of Object) - and since it's a *virtual* method, standard Java polymorphism takes over.

---

Now, [`Comparator#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) *imposes an additional restriction*, which is why it is specified as part of the interface.

> ..this method can return true *only if* the specified object is also a comparator and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator.

However, since the coverse need to be true, then not overloading `equals` doesn't break the new requirement.

> Note that it is always safe not to override Object.equals(Object).. [as then different comparator instances will never be equal].